# Getting error to deploy the BPEL project on weblogic 12c server

Tags: soa, weblogic12c, bpel

Using Oracle 12c I am getting this error during BPEL project deployment. Can you please help ?

> Deploying on partition "default" of
>   "/Domain_DefaultDomain/DefaultDomain/DefaultServer" ... Deploying on
>   "/Domain_DefaultDomain/DefaultDomain/DefaultServer" failed! There was
>   an error deploying the composite on DefaultServer: Deployment Failed:
>   Error occurred during deployment of component: WFTF_XAProcess_SWF_BPEL
>   to service engine: implementation.bpel for composite:
>   WFTF_XAProcess_SWF: ORABPEL-05215
>
> Error while loading process. The process domain is encountering the
>   following errors while loading the process "WFTF_XAProcess_SWF_BPEL"
>   (composite
>   "default/WFTF_XAProcess_SWF!3.0*soa_4c295eb0-2653-4780-8155-360a6d3297e6"):
>   Validation of BPEL2.0 process failed.. This error contained an
>   exception thrown by the underlying process loader module. Check the
>   exception trace in the log (with logging level set to debug mode). If
>   there is a patch installed on the server verify that the
>   bpelcClasspath domain property includes the patch classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check out soa_server1(the name of your soa server)-diagnostic.log. If there is a logging level is set to debug mode you can see more detailed log. It will help you analyze a cause of your error.

Comment: this error coming due to version wrong in spring xml.